# How to implement IComparer as inner class

Tags: c#, icomparer

So i have this simple class:

```
public class Mobile : IComparable
{
    private string _manufactor;
    private int _model;
    private decimal _price;

    public Mobile(string manufactor, int model, decimal price)
    {
        _manufactor = manufactor;
        _model = model;
        _price = price;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return _price.CompareTo((obj as Mobile)._price);
    }

    public class MobileModelComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return (x as Mobile)._model - (y as Mobile)._model;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the inner class `MobileModelComparer` need to implement `compare` between 2 `Mobile` object according `_model` property.

So my question is how to reach this `Compare` method from main ?

```
I try Mobile.MobileModelComparer
```

Comment: "I try `Mobile.MobileModelComparer`" How did you try it? What error do you get?  `new Mobile.MobileModelComparer();` should work just fine.

Comment: Not sure I understand...this should work: `var mobileModelComparer = new Mobile.MobileModelComparer(); mobileModelComparer.Compare(x, y);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `MobileModelComparer`. You could use `new` each time that you need an instance; however, since the object has no state, making it a static readonly instance would work:

```
public class MobileModelComparer : IComparer {
    public static IComparer Instance {get;} = new MobileModelComparer();
    ... // The rest of your code
}
```

You can now use `Mobile.MobileModelComparer.Instance.Compare(a, b)`

Alternatively, you could make `Instance` a property of `Mobile`, like this:

```
public static IComparer ModelComparer {get;} = new MobileModelComparer();
public class MobileModelComparer : IComparer {
    ... // The rest of your code
}
```

and use it like this: `Mobile.ModelComparer.Compare(a, b)`

**Note:** For C# prior to version 6 remove `{get;}` and add `readonly` to make `Instance` a static readonly field:

```
public static readonly IComparer Instance = new MobileModelComparer();
```

Comment: Your last line should be `Mobile.MobileModelComparer.Instance.Compare(a, b)` because `MobileModelComparer` is a nested class. Personally, when I do this pattern I put the singleton on the outside class so you could do `Mobile.ComparerInstance.Compare(a, b)`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the comment! Both items make perfect sense.

Comment: Very good answer, but I have one doubt, Compare method is applied on Mobile objects value and it will be created already because base class constructor will be called first, So why do we need to create instance of MobileModelComparer. We can create instance of Mobile also, please clarify.

Comment: @viveknuna C# nested classes are not in any way attached to instances of their outer classes, so you need to create instances separately. The need to create an instance of comparator in the first place is an unfortunate side effect of inability to implement interface methods in a static class.

Answer (score 0):

All an inner class does is change the name scoping, so you would create one just like it was in a namespace:

```
IComparer comparer = new Mobile.MobileModelComparer();
```